# How to set unique price for each simple product for configurable product

Tags: php, magento

I'm using configurable products for selecting size and shop branch of item. But i can't set unique price for each variant, as i understand i can only set price price relation to attribute. But in different branches this relation is different.

How can i set unique price for each item?

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an extension](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/) for this purpose.